# Reading from a file and excluding words using Scanner

Tags: java, string, hashmap, compare, java.util.scanner

Im currently trying to write a program that counts the amounts of times different words are being used in a text, and then attach the values to a hashmap. In the main part of the program i use a scanner to read in the file with the text, and i initiate the GenWordCtr with another scanner thats supposed to read in a file with words i want excluded (words like "this, her, that"). Ive made sure that the string sent to op.process is lowercased, however when i run the program it still adds all the values that i want excluded from the statistics. What am i doing wrong? I know the main program works, ive tried it with single words.

TLDR - i want words excluded using a scanner to read in a text, for some reason they arent being excluded in the "process" operation of my program.

```
    package textproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Holgersson {

    public static final String[] REGIONS = { "blekinge", "bohuslän", "dalarna", "dalsland", "gotland", "gästrikland",
            "halland", "hälsingland", "härjedalen", "jämtland", "lappland", "medelpad", "närke", "skåne", "småland",
            "södermanland", "uppland", "värmland", "västerbotten", "västergötland", "västmanland", "ångermanland",
            "öland", "östergötland" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("../lab1/nilsholg.txt"));
        Scanner stopwords = new Scanner(new File("undantagsord.txt"));
        s.useDelimiter("(\\s|,|\\.|:|;|!|-|\\?|'|\\\")+"); // se handledning

        TextProcessor gen = new GeneralWordCounter(stopwords);

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next().toLowerCase();

            gen.process(word);

        }

        s.close();

        gen.report();
    }
}


package textproc;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeneralWordCounter implements TextProcessor {

    private Map<String, Integer> m;
    private Scanner excep;

    GeneralWordCounter(Scanner r){
        Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.m = m;
        excep = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String word) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean bin = false;
        while(excep.hasNext() && bin == false) {
            if(word.equals(excep.next().toLowerCase())) {
                bin = true;
            }
        }
        if(!bin) {
            if(m.containsKey(word)) {
                m.put(word, (m.get(word) + 1));
            }
            else {
                m.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void report() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(String key : m.keySet()) {
            if(m.get(key) >= 200) {
            System.out.println(key + " - " + m.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand the logic of your code until I see the actual input and output

Comment: Input from the scanners? Here are examples from both of them:

Scanner main program (String word in process) : 

"Den signade dag, som vi nu här se
av himmelen till oss nedkomma,
han blive oss säll"

Scanner excep (text with exceptions) :                                                          

han hon en ett och att det i som hade på de inte var den sig så för

Comment: you need to share your complete code.

Comment: Done, the code was divided in two different classes and i assume im doing something wrong in the process part of the second class, thats why i only posted it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same Scanner instance for `stopwords` inside the loop, which might be getting exhausted within few number of below loops.

```
 TextProcessor gen = new GeneralWordCounter(stopwords);

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next().toLowerCase();

        gen.process(word);

    }
```

Imagine this way, you have started above loop and passed the Scanner instance and when you called `process` method it started loop for word and reached to end of the file for second Scanner. Now, in the next loop you again called `process` method but this time pointer will be already at the end of the file as you are using same instance. So, you won't get expected output.

Instead, you need to create new instance of Scanner for each `process` method call.

```
 public void process(String word) {
     Scanner excep = new Scanner(new File("undantagsord.txt"));
      // your code.
```

Comment: Ahh, yeah that makes sense. I just managed  to solve the problem by saving all the words to an arraylist that i initiated in the constructor of GenWordCtr, is there a better way to solve it just using the scanner or is the arraylist the smoothest alternative?

Comment: I think, ArrayList would be better solution instead of Scanner.